# Building a word up with a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program using python for class that works like this:

```
'Enter a word: " (EG Stack)
```

Then it outputs

```
S
St
Sta
Stac
Stack
```

I believe that it would use a looping function, but I'm completely stuck!

Comment: What are you stuck on? Show us the code in which you are stuck.

Comment: The thing is I don't really have much code, but here is what I have so far
msg = input("Enter a word: ")
length = int(len(msg))
for c in msg:
I'm just really stuck.

Comment: Imagine you're a computer, then write down the process you would use to do this (in English) and run through it. After you're satisfied that a computer could follow those instructions, translate it into Python.

Comment: First off thanks for the quick replies, but I still don't know how to do it Tigerhawk, I tried doing it in Pseudocode earlier and I just can't get it.

Comment: Try harder. Try until you shout. Then take a walk for a few minutes, then try some more. Look at all your notes, go over the things you've learned, and check the assignment text for hints.

Comment: Go even more basic than pseudocode: pretend you're telling a four-year old what to do. "This is your word. What is the first letter of your word?" That's about the level of instruction that a computer understands (you might even have to explain to it what "first" means). Examine each step you need to take and explain it in the simplest possible terms.

Comment: Ok so what I've made so far is:

http://pastebin.com/85A5eMyG
  
This works for some words but if it's anything shorter than 5 characters I get 'IndexError: string index out of range' - this is the bit I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Just fixed the formatting

Comment: It works!
http://pastebin.com/CDzNfdbJ

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = raw_input("Enter a word: ") #raw_input will convert the input into a string 
                                  #otherwise it would crash without quotation marks

word = ""                         #Initialize a variable

for letter in msg:                #Cycle through each letter
   word += letter                 #Adds that letter to your string
   print(word)                    #Prints out the current letters
```

Comment: @NiklasR doesn't the fact that they are all separate print statements add the other newline?

Comment: Yes; that's why you don't need another one. Your version will print a blank line between each line of content.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Exactly. I am just trying to follow the OP's example where there are blank lines between each string.

Comment: @NiklasR I realize you were correcting my comment, thank you, I will fix that now

Comment: I'm 97% sure that the OP only has a blank line between each line of content because they aren't yet experienced with SO's formatting.

Comment: Could I propose an edit to the post with my reason being that it seems like the OP's intention?

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to achieve your output. Each iteration of the for loop increments an index variable (`i` below), and this is used to display ever increasing slices from the string.

```
>>> word = 'Stack'
>>> for i in range(1, len(word)+1):
...     print word[:i]
... 
S
St
Sta
Stac
Stack

>>> word='Slicing'
>>> for i in range(1, len(word)+1):
...     print word[:i]
... 
S
Sl
Sli
Slic
Slici
Slicin
Slicing
```

You can read about slicing in the Python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score -1):

http://pastebin.com/CDzNfdbJ 
Got it, I don't really understand it, but it works.